# transform translate rotate order

Tags: css, 3d, transform

I was working on a project making 3D cubes. I spent hours looking for mistake in CSS. I was not able to find any. Then I started fiddling with the code. To my amusement if I am using translate before rotate in transform like
`transform: translateX(value px) rotateY(value deg);`
the result will be a broken cube. It is only effecting top, right and left sides of the cube.
While there is a reverse effect on bottom and back sides of the cube i.e. `transform: rotateX(vlaue deg) translateY(value px);` is giving me collapsed back and bottom. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n3tbkf1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

consider the two transform orders:

1. `transform: translateX(value px) rotateY(value deg);`

In this case rotateY is done first and then translateX,and you get a broken cube because of `transform-origin` property.If you remove this it will be perfect.

> when the transform-origin property is applied to a translate transform
>   function that there is no apparent visual difference in the outcome.
>   This is because the element impacted by the transform is moved without
>   changing it’s shape, size, or rotation.

```css
.wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
          perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50%  100px;
          perspective-origin: 50%  100px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
          animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
}

.cube div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #66cc00;
  background: pink;
}

.cube .back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
          transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.cube .front {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
          transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.cube .right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(-270deg);
          transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(-270deg);
}

.cube .left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px) rotateY(270deg);
          transform: translateX(-100px) rotateY(270deg);
}

.cube .top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px) rotateX(-90deg);
          transform: translateY(-100px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.cube .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px) rotateX(90deg);
          transform: translateY(100px) rotateX(90deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
            transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
            transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="cube">
        <div class="front">front</div>
        <div class="back">back</div>
        <div class="top">top</div>
        <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
        <div class="left">left</div>
        <div class="right">right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

2.`transform: rotateX(value deg) translateY(value px);`

In this case translateY is done first and then rotateX,so you need transform-origin property.It allows you to change the position of transformed elements.

> Here transform-origin is applied for rotateX as its done second.Thus
>   transform-origin changes the point at which the element transforms
>   rather than moving the entire element